# images cant be added to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, model-view-controller

I am trying to add one or more than one files/images, to my database for each inspection I have/create.

```
public function inspectieOpslaan($data){    
        $sql = "SELECT `id`
                FROM `qa_inspection_document`
                WHERE `part_id` = :part_id;";
        $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':part_id', $_POST['part_id']);
        $statement->execute();
        $partID = $statement->fetchColumn();
        if($statement->rowCount() == 0) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `inspectiedocument_file` (title, inspection_requirement, inspection_resources, part_id, standard, extra_document, datum) VALUES (:title, :requirement, :resources, :partId, :standard, :extra_Document, :datum);";
            $statement->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
            $statement->bindParam(':requirement', $_POST['inspection_requirement']);
            $statement->bindParam(':resources', $_POST['inspection_resources']);
            $statement->bindParam(':part_id', $_POST['part_id']);
            $statement->bindParam(':standard', $_POST['standard']);
            $statement->bindParam(':extra_Document', $_POST['extra_Document']);
            $statement->bindParam(':datum', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));
            $statement->execute();
            $partID = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE `inspectiedocument_file` SET
                `title` = :title,
                `inspection_requirement` = :requirement,
                `inspection_resources` = :resources,
                `standard` = :standard,
                `extra_document` = :status,
                WHERE `part_id` = :part_id;";

        $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $_POST['part_id']);
        $statement->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
        $statement->bindParam(':requirement', str2Bool($_POST['inspection_requirement']));
        $statement->bindParam(':resources', str2Bool($_POST['inspection_resources']));
        $statement->bindParam(':standard', str2Bool($_POST['standard']));
        $statement->bindParam(':datum', $_POST['datum']);
        $statement->execute();


        if($data['aantalAfgekeurd'] > 0)
            $resultaat = 'nok';
        else
            $resultaat = 'ok';

        $temp = array();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `qa_purchase_order` (`part_id`, `order_number`, `row_number`, `quantity`, `inspected_quantity`, `approved_quantity`) VALUES (:partId, :orderNumber, :rowNumber, :quantity, :inspectedQuantity, :approvedQuantity)";
        $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':partId', $data['partId']);
        $statement->bindParam(':orderNumber', $data['inkooporderNummer']);
        $statement->bindParam(':rowNumber', $data['regelNummer']);
        $statement->bindParam(':quantity', $data['totaalAantal']);
        $statement->bindParam(':inspectedQuantity', $data['aantalGecontroleerd']);
        $statement->bindParam(':approvedQuantity', $data['aantalGoedgekeurd']);
        $statement->execute();
        $purchaseId = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
        $_SESSION['qa']['group'] = $purchaseId;


        if(isset($_FILES['newDocuments'])){
            $_FILES['documents'] = $_FILES['newDocuments'];
                uploadFile('qa\inspections'); // <-- include.php

            foreach($_SESSION['documents'] as $file)
            {               

                $sql = "INSERT INTO `inspectiedocument_file` (title, inspection_requirement, inspection_resources, part_id, standard, extra_document, datum) VALUES (:title, :requirement, :resources, :partId, :standard, :extra_Document, :datum);";

                $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
                $statement->bindParam(':title', $sjabloon['titel']);
                $statement->bindParam(':requirement', $sjabloon['inspectieEis']);
                $statement->bindParam(':resources', $sjabloon['inspectieMiddelen']);
                $statement->bindParam(':partId', $partId);
                $statement->bindParam(':standard', $sjabloon['markeerStandaard']);
                $statement->bindParam(':extra_Document', $file);
                $statement->bindParam(':datum', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));
                $statement->execute();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then In another folder I have the following code for adding the image to the database (I didnt include the code for the rest of the field since they work fine)

```
<td class='label'>Extra informatie:</td>
            <td>
                <!-- -->
                <table class="clean">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="none">
                            <table class="clean" id="newDocuments">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="none"><!-- Placeholder voor addDocument(); --></td>
                                    <td class="none">
                                        <input class="width" type="file" name="newDocuments[]" />
                                        <img src="images/badge-circle-plus.png" onclick="addDocument('newDocuments');" alt="Document toevoegen" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
```

and this JS code:

```
<script>
    function controleer()
    {
        var textNeeded = true;
        var reacties = $('input[name^=newDocuments]');
        var bestaandeReacties = $('table#documents tr').length - 1; // - 1 is voor th               
        for(var i = 0; i < reacties.length; i++) {
            if(reacties.eq(i).val() == '' && bestaandeReacties <= 0) {
                reacties.eq(i).addClass('error');   
                setDocMelding = true;
            } else {
                textNeeded = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

AND FINALLY IN MY VIEW i HAVE THE FOLLWOING:

```
if(isset($sjabloon['extra_document']) && !empty($sjabloon['extra_document']))
                {
                    $dochtml .= '<tr>';
                        $dochtml .= '<td class="label">Extra document:</td>';
                        $dochtml .= '<td><a target="_blank" href="'. $url .'uploads/qa/sjabloon/'. urlencode($sjabloon['extra_document']) .'">'. $sjabloon['extra_document'] .'</a></td>';
                    $dochtml .= '</tr>';
                }
```

IN THE END ALL THE VALUES ARE ADDED TO THE DATABSE EXPECT FOR THE images it doesnt mattter how many imgae I upload, they have no value in the database, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where you put the file  in $_SESSION['documents']      " foreach($_SESSION['documents'] as $file"

Comment: Can we see the definition of the database?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu I am not understanding what you ask of me.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I created the databse in phpmyadmin normally is that help or you want the definition?

Comment: you have use $_SESSION['documents'] in foreach() loop.I want to know where you put the file name in $_SESSION['documents'] variable?

Comment: The database definition is important: is the column where you're trying to store images the proper type?

Comment: @JayBlanchard, the definition is good because I have a way of adding one image or file to the databse and it works, only if I addmore than one it wont work.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu is this what you mean: $statement->bindParam(':extra_Document', $file);

Comment: @JayBlanchard not sure how.

Comment: There will be error logs somewhere on your server, both for MySQL and for Apache/PHP. It will depend on the type of server.

Comment: @S.N, yes, unable to find where you put value in  $_SESSION['documents']

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu I changed $_SESSION to $_FILESbut it didnt work either. I think the problems come with the names, I have onclick="addDocument('newDocuments'), could this be the problem?

Comment: Did you sure your js function addDocument() was executed properly? Also instead of passing name you can pass 'this' also.Also I am not able to find your addDocument() function also.